# Import multi-line address field into Salesforce using DBAmp

Tags: import, salesforce, dbamp

Addresses in Salesforce are a [structured compound data type](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/compound_fields_address.htm).  As such, different fields exist for the street, city, state, and country.  The street field is a single field.  How does one import multi-line street addresses such as:

```
1 Street Line
2 Street Line
3 Street Line
City, State, 12345
Country
```

using [DBAmp](http://www.forceamp.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to embed newline characters `\n` in the field value with the T-SQL [`char()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187323.aspx) function.  Thus, the solution is:

```
address1 + char(10) + address2 [+ char(10) + addressN ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, have you run into any trouble?

On Account the BillingStreet / ShippingStreet is a textarea field. Meaning good old newline character `\n` should do just fine, as long as the total length < 255.

Map the remaining address components to BillingState etc and you're good to go?

Sorry if the answer is a bit generic but as stupid as it sounds - try it out on few acconts before full import and you should get the hang of it. Unless it's a question about string splitting in SQL Server...

Comment: Unfortunately, the newline character `\n` is not working. This may be a DBAmpism. When I upsert a BillingStreet containing `'This\nis\na\ntest'`, Salesforce dutifully displays `This\nis\na\ntest` on one line.  How can I escape the newline character `\n` in the source field so that it will be recognized by Salesforce?

Comment: Looks like DBAmp's problem indeed (and your `\n` is already being escaped by it). In the developer console it works like a charm: `insert new Account(Name = 'whatever', BillingStreet = 'This\nis\na\ntest');` Maybe try with `\r`? What do your SQL Server tables display, 1 line with `\n` or a proper multiline content? Last but not least - try asking at salesforce.stackexchange.com too ;)